# How to compile strings containing Directives in Angular; $compile and $interpolate don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to be able to use dynamic strings that may contain directives. The problem is I can't seem to get $compile nor $interpolate to work. I have the following in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTLHyYUGz3v7o4xlaasS?p=preview)

*index.html*

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.badge}}</li>
    </div>
  </body>
```

*app.js*

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $element, $compile) {

  $scope.users = [{
    badge: $compile('<p><name-badge name="Carl Sagan"></name-badge></p>')($scope)
  },{
    badge: $compile('<p><name-badge name="Richard Dawkins"></name-badge></p>')($scope)
  },{
    badge: $compile('<p><name-badge name="Cecilia Payne"></name-badge></p>')($scope)
  }];
});

app.directive('nameBadge', function ($compile) {

  return {
    template: '<strong>Hi, I\'m {{name}}',

    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.name = $attrs.name;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `circular structure to json` error isn't being throwing by `$compile` service. It occurs because you're trying to bind an invalid value to the view, in this case, a compiled element.

The "correct" way to add the returning value of `$compile` to the DOM is by using the `$element` service:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $element, $compile) {
  $element.append($compile('<p><name-badge name="Micah"></name-badge></p>')($scope));
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPsrqyv2T6ne5qLoDWiP?p=preview)

I said "correct" because you shouldn't be doing that kind of DOM manipulation in a controller. You should try to use a directive instead.

Comment: Yes I am doing it in a directive in the actual application; just wrote it up quickly this way to illustrate the general case. Thanks much :)

Comment: Actually this won't work for the actual use case. Because the strings are rendered inside a ng-repeat directive. So I think I need to be able to attach the compiled value to the scope? Here's an updated plunker to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/DPsrqyv2T6ne5qLoDWiP?p=preview

Comment: @micahblu That link points to the same plunker I have posted :\

Comment: Try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/PTLHyYUGz3v7o4xlaasS?p=preview @MichaelBenford

Comment: I guess a way around this would be to not use the ng-repeat, to instead build a string of all the values from the loop then compile and append as you've shown

Comment: @micahblu Your new code is pretty much the same as the original one: you're trying to bind an element to the view using interpolation, and that fails for the very same reason I've mentioned before. Take a look at [this modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S1yAxy0Y4XEPSYBw4wK8?p=preview). It does what you (apparently) want but by using a directive instead. Let me know if it works so I can update my answer.

Comment: The problem is the string values need be dynamic and not hardwired into a directive. They would come from a $http.get() request as unformatted literal strings

Comment: @micahblu What string values are dynamic, exactly? The names or the markup?

Comment: I'm expecting an array of strings from the server. Its actual copy (content) to be displayed, that may or may not have directives inside them.